# One chrome extension consuming resourses from another

Tags: google-chrome-extension, layer, content-script

I have a Chrome extension that simply contains a series of content scripts that change an existing page.

This extension is meant to be shared with other users.

But on top of that extension, I want to add more functionality, create another "layer" that will be enabled only to me. And this layer should be able to call methods from that extension.

Is there a way to create this layer as a second extension, but make it somehow reference the other and access its methods?  I don't want to copy/paste code and have to update everything twice when necessary.

Comment: It'd be a nasty security hole if you could.  Inject the common code, or use messaging, or rethink the approach.

Comment: Could you tell me more about the security issues?

Comment: Or other approaches?

Comment: EG: Good extension is trusted to send pictures to trusted server.  If extensions could share code (easily), then bad extension could use that same code to send images to evil server -- possibly without even appearing to have camera permissions.

Comment: You could *maybe* put shared *.js files, etc, in common directory.  Haven't investigated this in modern Chrome.

Comment: Interesting....if the top layer contains the entire other extension in a subfolder.....